# How to prove: $\int { dx \over {x^n z^m}} = {{-1 \over{(n-1)ax^{n-1}z^{m-1}}} + {b(2-n-m) \over a(n-1)} \int {dx \over x^{n-1}z^m} }$?

Tags: integration

The equation is given below where $z = a+ bx$

$\int { dx \over {x^n z^m}} = {{-1 \over{(n-1)ax^{n-1}z^{m-1}}} + {b(2-n-m) \over a(n-1)} \int {dx \over x^{n-1}z^m} }$

Integration by parts gives:

$(a+bx)^{-m}\int x^{-n}dx - \int ({d \over dx}(a+bx)^{-m} \int x^{-n} dx)dx  $

$= {1 \over{-(n-1)(a+bx)^m x^{n-1}} }- {mb \over (n-1)} \int {dx \over (a+bx)^{m+1}x^{n-1}}$

Now the problem is I can't match the powers of my equation with the given RHS. Either x or z has a different order from which I found! How can I do that right?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: yes. I know that "integration by parts" is involved here but I can't figure that out!

Comment: What exactly can't you figure out? Please show some of your attempts and thoughts instead of just posting the problem statement

Comment: added my attempts

Comment: Good question. You can also try to use the following $$\frac{1}{(a+bx)^{m+1}}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{a}{(a+bx)^{m+1}}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{(a+bx)^{m}}-\frac{1}{a}\frac{bx}{(a+bx)^{m+1}}$$ and then integrate by parts some more with $u=x$

Comment: Thanks. let me try

Answer (score 1):

Idea, too long for a comment:
$$
\int{dx\over{x^n z^m}} =
{{-1 \over{(n-1)ax^{n-1}z^{m-1}}} + {b(2-n-m)\over a(n-1)}\int{dx\over x^{n-1}z^m} }
$$
is equivalent to
$$
{1\over{x^n z^m}} =
\frac{d}{dx}{{-1 \over{(n-1)ax^{n-1}z^{m-1}}} + {b(2-n-m)\over a(n-1)}{1\over x^{n-1}z^m}},
$$
and this must be easy to check.

EDIT:

Your formula is **wrong**: when $a =1$, $b = 0$:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}{{-1\over{(n-1)ax^{n-1}z^{m-1}}}} =
\frac{d}{dx}{{-1\over{(n-1)x^{m+n-2}}}} =
\frac{m + n - 2}{(n - 1)x^{m+n-1}},
$$
while:
$$
{1\over{x^n z^m}} - {b(2-n-m)\over a(n-1)}{1\over x^{n-1}z^m}
 = {1\over{x^{m+n}}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks but I really want to get that by integrating the LHS.

Comment: I am still helpless guys. please help me!!!

Comment: @AtiqurRahman, your formula is wrong, see the edit.

Comment: I assume here none of a or b must be zero. Thanks